# How are nullable fields handled in pyodbc parameter markers?

Tags: python, sql-server, nullable, pyodbc

I am using pyodbc to access a MSSQL database
I have a table with nullable fields. I want to pass variables into an insert statement with parameter markers.

I have tried values of None and NULL

```
foo= "NULL"    #this field is sometimes nullable
baz =152 

sql_query = "insert into my_table(field1, field2)(?,?)"
cursor.execute(baz, foo)
cnxn.commit()

foo= None
sql_query = "insert into my_table(field1, field2)(?,?)"
cursor.execute(sql_query , baz, foo)
cnxn.commit()
```

I'm getting this data error:

> ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid
>   character value for cast specification (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Is there another way I can represent a null value that can be passed in to pyodbc?

Comment: You forgot to pass `sql_query` as the first argument of the `.execute` method. Try that with `foo = None`.

Comment: Simply use `None` instead of quoted `"NULL"`.

Comment: Thank you, I see parameter markers do accept None for nullable fields. My logic in assigning the variables wasn't correctly assigning it.